# How to pass different file handlers to javascript FileReader?

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, filereader

The HTML5 FileReader API is quite handy for loading files client-side from the user's desktop. This is the asynchronous javascript pattern, found elsewhere on stackoverflow to use this API:

```
var fileHandler = function(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile){
        var fileName = theFile.name;
        return function(e){
            console.log(fileName); // I want a callback here
        };
    })(currentFile);   
    reader.readAsText(currentFile);
}
```

I want to use the file upload button in many different places in my application, and process the file differently in each. What's the most efficient way to pass different processing callbacks in to the fileHandler function so that I don't have to copy the rest of the function code (creating the FileReader, defining an onload function, readAsText)?